# spring boot 2.1.6 with zipkin, debugging the project using spring boot application throws an Exception

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, zipkin

I am using the `Zipkin 5.6.11`

I append `mysql` url:

```
 jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/....&statementInterceptors=brave.mysql.TracingStatementInterceptor
```

but when I debug the project using spring boot application, it throws an Exception caused by not found the class TracingStatementInterceptor:

> java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load statement interceptor
>   'brave.mysql.TracingStatementInterceptor'.
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: brave.mysql.TracingStatementInterceptor

The dependency is

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
     <artifactId>brave-instrumentation-mysql</artifactId>
     <version>5.6.11</version>
     <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
             <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
             <artifactId>brave</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
         <exclusion>
             <groupId>io.zipkin.zipkin2</groupId>
             <artifactId>zipkin</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
         <exclusion>
             <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
             <artifactId>zipkin-reporter</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please, provide the dependencies. What MySQL connector do you use? Try to use `brave.mysql8.TracingStatementInterceptor`.

Comment: com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource] - create connection SQLException

Comment: You cannot use what you exclude: `io.zipkin.brave`:`brave`.

Comment: You mean that I should not exclude: `io.zipkin.brave`:`brave`?

Comment: I annotate the exclusion of `io.zipkin.brave`, but it still throws the same exception